# How to fix SQL connection leaks in this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am getting this error on my website:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. 
>   The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the
>   pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in
>   use and max pool size was reached.

This is the C# class that is being reused everywhere (I think the leak is here):

```
public class Generator
{

SqlConnection cn = null; // new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    public SqlConnection Connection {
        get {
            if (cn == null) {
            cn = new SqlConnection("Server=xxxxx,1433;Database=xxxxx;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;");
            }
            if(cn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                cn.Open();

            return cn;
        }
    }

}
```

Then in my methods I use it like this:

```
        var cmd = _generator.Connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable";
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
        reader.Close();
```

**EDIT:** In the class of my methods I attempt to share the same SQL connection across multiple methods like this:

```
private Generator _generator;

public HomeController()
{
    InitializeConnection();
}

private void InitializeConnection()
{
    _generator = new Generator();
}
```

Can anyone see how I can fix the leak or what is causing my max pool issue?

Comment: Not being a c# developer, but shouldn't it be `this.cn` or similar, to indicate that cn is a class variable, not just a local variable inside your connection method?

Comment: You are not closing your connections anywhere.

Comment: @MarcB - If the reference is not ambiguous, there is no need to qualify the variable with `this`.

Comment: And I strongly recommend putting your closings (connections and readers depending on how you end up organizing them) in a finally.  You don't want to leak connections if exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Is _generator created in each page? Then that's the source of your leak.

Comment: I am trying to reuse a private member. I updated my question with how I am initializing the private member

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `using` blocks to make sure the objects are disposed.

```
using (var cmd = _generator.Connection.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //DO SOMETHING
            }
    }
}
```

I also wouldn't use a `Connection` property. It's better to open and close connections as needed and allow connection pooling to do its job.

Comment: You're focusing on the wrong object here, while the command object implements IDisposable and certainly should be disposed of, he is most likely not disposing of the connection stored in the `Generator` instance, and leaving those for GC.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: true, but he's only got the one connection, unless he has multiple instances of `_generator`. Also, I did tell him I wouldn't use the `Connection` property.

Comment: I am trying to reuse a private member. I updated my question with how I am initializing the private member.

Comment: Stop doing that. ADO.NET is smarter than you in terms of reusing connections. Just create and open the connection when you need it.

Answer (score 4):

The connection is not getting closed, only the reader.  You can use the [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx) with the [CommandBehavior.CloseConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx) - but if you use ExecuteCommand, there is no such useful option, and you have to use the Close method on your connection object.

Answer (score 3):

Since your Generator class is not static, every time you create a Generator() object you'll be getting a new connection that isn't closed. You've got a few things you want to do:

- Convert your Generator class to the Singleton pattern, or remove it completely
- Have Generator implement IDisposable and call cn.Dispose()
- Ensure each time you call Generator.Connection that you wrap it in a using (...) block

Answer (score 2):

For a start, your Generator class owns an IDisposable object (an SqlConnection), and so should implement IDisposable itself.

Next your use of an underscore prefix (`_generator.Connection.CreateCommand()`) suggests that _generator is probably a field of your other data access classes, which therefore need to implement IDisposable themselves, ...

Based on the code you've posted, you need to eliminate the `Generator` class, which appears to serve no useful purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dispose of the connection when you're done with it.

In the code you've shown in the question, here's what I would do:

1. Make `Generator` implement `IDisposable` by disposing of the connection object when the generator is disposed
2. Since `_generator` looks like a field, the class with the second piece of code should probably also implement `IDisposable` and dispose the `_generator` contents

Also, note that the command object is also implementing `IDisposable` and you should always dispose of objects that implement `IDisposable` that you create.