# Nhibernate, SQL Server and IIS 7.5 Connection leak : Timeout prior to obtaining a connection from the app pool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, memory-leaks, autofac

I have an MVC application deployed on 3 separate servers (Test, Staging and Production Environment). Test and Staging server are doing fine but occassionally, the production server do pull this error

> System.InvalidOperationException
>   Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection >from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in >use and max pool size was reached.

The full stack trace as captured by elmah is as shown below.

[image: Timeout error message]

The production server is on SQL Server 2008 and IIS 7.5.

My Nhibernate Driver connector is as shown below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
    <property    name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect,NHibernate</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">0</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
    <mapping assembly="BusinessLogic"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is my Get current session Method

```
 public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            ISession currentSession = context.Items[CURRENT_NHIBERNATE_SESSION_KEY] as ISession;

            if (currentSession == null)
            {
                currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
                context.Items[CURRENT_NHIBERNATE_SESSION_KEY] = currentSession;
            }
            if (currentSession.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            }
            if (!currentSession.IsConnected)
            {
                currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            }
            if (!currentSession.IsOpen)
            {
                currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            }
            if (currentSession.IsDirty())
            {
                currentSession.Clear();
            }

            return currentSession;
        }
```

I used IRepository pattern for all my business logic. One of my method is shown here:

```
 public IList<CourseRequirement> getCourseRequirement(int requirementId)
            {
                ISession  session = _courseRequirment.CurrentSession;
                var cr = session.QueryOver<CourseRequirement>().Where(x => x.RequirementId == requirementId);
                return cr.List<CourseRequirement>();
            }
```

In addition, I am using autofac for dependency injection. I can also see this in the inner exception every time it happens.

> System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to
>   create a controller of type 'ASSEMBLY.Controllers.AccountController'.
>   Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
>   ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type
>   'NHibernateRepository`2'. ---> Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have
>   occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size
>   was reached. (See inner exception for details.) --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have
>   occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size
>   was reached.

**What I have done**

I have checked these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039206/getting-timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-obtaining-a-connect), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398323/how-to-fix-sql-connection-leaks-in-this-code) and many more. Others like [how-to-fix-sql-connection-leaks-in-this-code](http://how-to-fix-sql-connection-leaks-in-this-code) suggested  putting the sql in using statements. 
Almost, all the links suggested connection leak in the application and recommends putting all transaction in a using statement.

Implement that implies rewriting most methods in my business logic.

I am worried because this is not the only application I have written this way and besides Test and staging environment are fine. From logging report, this often happens when the site is on low traffic e.g 6:00 am, 3.00 am but the time is not fixed.

Kindly help

**Update**
This is my autofac Dependency resolver(I can see from the inner exception that autofac could not instantiate some services occasionally

```
 public class FormDependencyResolver
    {
        public static void RegisterDependencies()
        {

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);


            builder.Register(c =>
                //register FakeHttpContext when HttpContext is not available
                HttpContext.Current != null ?
                (new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current) as HttpContextBase) :
                (new FakeHttpContext("~/") as HttpContextBase))
                .As<HttpContextBase>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Request)
                .As<HttpRequestBase>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Response)
                .As<HttpResponseBase>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Server)
                .As<HttpServerUtilityBase>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Session)
                .As<HttpSessionStateBase>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();



            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NHibernateRepository<,>)).As(typeof(IRepository<,>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<AsyncService>().As<IAsyncService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();//.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<SMSSender>().As<ISMSSender>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<SMSAccount>().As<ISMSAccount>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<BusinessLogic.Services.AuthenticationService>().As<IAuthenticationService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<PageHelper>().As<IPageHelper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<UtilityService>().As<IUtilityService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<WebWorker>().As<IWebWorker>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<DateTimeHelper>().As<IDateTimeHelper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<AuditService>().As<IAuditService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<HtmlHelper>().InstancePerDependency();
            builder.RegisterType<PaymentService>().As<IPaymentService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            IContainer container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening new session instances in each of those `if` statements. Several of them can be executed at once because there are not `else` statements. The previously opened session would go out of scope without calling `Dispose()`.

The code below is everything you should need. Just make sure to dispose the session instance at the end of the HTTP request.

```
private static readonly object syncObject = new Object();

public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
{   
     lock (syncObject)
     {
         HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
         ISession currentSession = context.Items[CURRENT_NHIBERNATE_SESSION_KEY] as ISession;

         if (currentSession == null)
         {
             currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
         }

         context.Items[CURRENT_NHIBERNATE_SESSION_KEY] = currentSession;    

         return currentSession;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Dmitry S, but the current session instanciated   outside the if statement. I mean we have just one instance but multiple assignment in the if statement.

Comment: `sessionFactory.OpenSession()` initializes a new session on every assignment.